Open Set is Equal To Union of Closed Sets
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $U\subset{X}$ be an open set. Then $U$ may be written as a union of closed sets.
I think I have a proof for this but I'm not quite sure, I feel like there must be something missing to it, or that it is not fully rigorous. I've seen some posts that proved it differently and more complicated, so I feel like mine might be wrong.
My Proof.
Let $V=\{x:x\in{J}\}$ where $J$ is any closed subset of $U$. If $x\in{V}$ then $x\in{U}$. If $x\in{U}$ then there exists an open ball $B(x,\delta)$ such that $B(x,\delta)\subset{U}$. Take an $0<\varepsilon<\delta$. Then the closed ball $C(x,\varepsilon)\subset{B(x,\delta)}\subset{U}$ is in V, as $x\in{C(x,\varepsilon)}$ then x is in $V$. So $V=U.$ We take $\bigcup\{x:x\in{V}\}=V=U$ and we are done.
I'm not quite sure if the union business I did at the end is correct, but besides that I can't really find a problem with it.

$U$ is a union of signleton sets.

In your argument, the elements of $V$ are sets, subsets of $U$. So $x\in V$ implies $x$ is a subset of $U$. But then $x\in U$ doesn't make sense, since a subset of $U$ isn't an element of $U$.

I see, thanks for the insight.

Any subset of a metric space is a union of closed sets and this  hardly requires any proof.  I am shocked at your statement that  you have seen some more complicated proofs than  yours!

Yes it's so obvious now that I see it, feels like it was right in front of me and I just didn't look.

I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to correct an error.

I suspect that the complicated proofs you've seen are proving that every open set is a countable union of closed sets, which is still true, and is a more interesting property.

Hi @GerryMyerson, I am a bit surprised by your vote to close. Leaving aside general controversy around solution-verification, isn't the point of questions where the OP is unsure of their reasoning that they might have made an error? It seems to me that the correct course of action is to write an answer that points out the mistake in this case. I feel like I have actually generally seen the practice of editing to correct errors in an OP's reasoning discouraged, for instance here.

@Izaak, I wrote a comment pointing out the mistake. OP took no action to correct the mistake, so I voted to close. OP has now corrected the mistake, and I have retracted my vote.

There are two cases to deal with: (1) $U = \emptyset$ and (2) $U \neq \emptyset$.
In Case (1), $U = \emptyset$ is a closed set.
In Case (2), we can write
$$
U = \bigcup \left\{ S_x = \{ x \}: x \in U \right\} 
$$
The proof is closed since every singleton set is a closed set in the metric space $(X, d)$.

Perfect. Thats most likely the solution the textbook wanted me to give, because its fairly simple and my textbook hasn't even used any mappings between metric spaces in their example problems.

Alternatively, I think it's easier to show that a closed set can be written as an intersection of open sets.
Let $F$ be a closed set of $\left( X,d \right)$ and $f$ the mapping such that,
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  f ~:~ \left(X,d\right) & \longrightarrow & \left( \mathbb{R} , |\cdot|\right)\\
  x & \longmapsto & d(x,F)
 \end{array} 
$$
$f$ is $1-$Lipschitz hence it's continuous. We have,
$$ F=\overline{F}=f^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace) = f^{-1} \left( \bigcap_ {n \geqslant 1} \left] -1/n,1/n\right[ \right) = \bigcap_ {n \geqslant 1} f^{-1} (\left] -1/n,1/n\right[)$$
We wrote $F$ as a (countable) intersection of open sets.
